# Чем является слово точно в предложении "А точно тебе же можно"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, части-речи

> А точно тебе же можно

Чем здесь является `точно`? И как правильно расставить знаки препинания?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что "же" в этой фразе лишнее. Или "А точно", одно из двух. Т.е. или "А точно тебе можно? или "Тебе же можно?"

Comment: Тут "А точно" в значении "Совсем забыл".

Comment: Вы просто не поставили знак препинания в конце предложения, поэтому мне показалось, что это был вопрос.

Comment: Пункт 2: https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/702/точно

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***А точно, тебе же можно.***

Обособлено вводное сочетание "а точно" в значении "действительно, в самом деле".

Сравнить: ***Действительно** (в самом деле), тебе же можно.*

**ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО**, вводное слово. Выражает уверенность говорящего в сообщаемом, употребляется для подтверждения, признания правильности **сказанного ранее**.

**КОММЕНТАРИИ**

– Может ли быть такое, что "а" будет **междометием**, а "точно" будет обособляться с обеих сторон как вводное слово?

– Может! Просто делаем еще одну паузу и обозначаем ее запятой. Тогда это будет не частица А, а обособленное **междометие А** со значением "совсем забыл". ***А, точно, тебе же можно***. Две запятые допускаются (здесь можно вспомнить правило о двух вводных словах, которые пишутся через запятую). Междометия и вводные слова в общем случае являются **модальными** словами.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ** (пояснение ответа от 22.04.2023 из чата)

Основным принципом в пунктуации, как я думаю, является **семантический** принцип. Для определенного содержания (семантики) мы по правилам подбираем **форму** (ищем разрешенные грамматические конструкции). Вот здесь такая схема: междометие + вводное слово + высказывание. А подходящее **лексическое наполнение** можно потом находить.

В примере лексическое наполнение было **задано**, **смысл** тоже указан автором: "А, совсем забыл, тебе же можно". Так что роль каждого слова определяется по схеме.

[Справочник по пунктуации](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_166)

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145523/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon---------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Почему частица? "А" — это союз, исправьте.

Comment: Более точно передаёт смысл: *А, ну да, тебе же можно.* "Ну да" тоже передаёт вспоминание после забывания. Теперь "ну да" будем считать вводным? У каждого слова своя история! В таких случаях замена не всегда корректно работает. Не надо считать все слова подтверждения, признания правильности вводными. Как мы знаем, лишь **некоторые** наречия начинают в процессе эволюции языка использоваться в качестве вводных. В таких случаях просто находите словарные или справочные статьи с похожими примерами.

Comment: Какой союз? Укажите значение по толковому словарю Кузнецова или Ефремовой.

Comment: 3) присоединяет к одному из членов предложения слова, группы слов, предложения; обычно со сл.: *именно, главное, **в самом деле**, значит, потому, следовательно, всё* и **т.п.** Указывает на развитие, дополнение, пояснение высказанной мысли; выражает характеристику, оценку сказанного.

Comment: "Точно", выражающее реакцию на сказанное и вспоминание забытого, вводным не является. При междометии "а" оно вообще произносится очень отдельно, можно заменить на "правильно" или "верно". В словаре у вводного "верно" значение сомнения, а вот словарные примеры с обособленным "верно", но не вводным: *Ты не забыл о своём обещании? - Верно [точно], забыл! Да ведь это наша ложка! - Наша, верно [точно].* А обособленное "действительно" тоже не всегда вводное, Грамота пишет, что трудно определить, но некоторые люди умеют.

Comment: Эти комментарии направлены на улучшение, исправления ответа, всё законно. А модераторы, скорее всего, просто на кнопку нажимают, когда что-то загорается, и даже не читают (комментарии о перемещении автоматические). Так что не парьтесь.

Comment: Короче так.  Опять начали ДИСКУССИЮ, что вы за человек такой!  Вам сказано "нельзя", а вы не понимаете.  Давайте свой ответ, если вы не согласны с моей оценкой значения слов.  Вы не уточняете или улучшаете, а отрицаете.   Есть поле ответа. Укажите, что это комментарии к моему ответу или что угодно напишите.  Пусть участники оценят ваше мнение. И в вашей оценка слова А я тоже не уверена, похоже на усиление слова точно. Частица легко переходит в междометие,  также все сочетание А точно имеет значение припоминания. Так что пока, пока.

Comment: Просто вы ответ обновили, будто выиграли. Так не пойдёт. А на самом деле просто сливаетесь, потому что уже ни в чём не уверены :)

Comment: У Грамоты, когда "а", всегда пишется "союз +...". Странно, что вы не заметили.

Comment: Ну да, сливаюсь. Что мне здесь делать: все молчат, никого нет, обратили внимание?  Наверное, я им не нравлюсь, мешаю работать. Неуверенность иногда полезна для развития, а уверенность настораживает. Человек не готов к диалогу, все знает. Другими словами, путь к деградации :))

Comment: Почему никого нет? Остальные два лайка поставили. *Неуверенность иногда полезна для развития* — протестую, в этом нет логики. Настораживает не уверенность, а упёртость и отсутствие должной реакции на факты (бывает похуже, чем у вас). В общем, не надо заменять на вводные слова, это не всегда корректно работает, как видим, здесь и на вводные, и на не вводные заменяется.

Comment: И где теперь эти лайки, всё удалили.  Вы и себя, и меня подставили, а еще возмущаетесь.  А вводные слова для вас – это вообще священная корова, рассуждать о них – это все равно что идти по минному полю, ага?  А для меня если слово занимает позицию вводного, то это вводное слово. Свободный стиль мышления, без вашей зажатости.

Comment: Вы шутите? Три лайка так и стоит. Ну не корова, а принципиально, как Розенталь говорил. Про минное поле смешно) При начальной позиции не обязательно вводное. Реакция часто выражается одним словом, — и что, всех их вводными считать? Если вклинивается в предложение, то другое дело. А "же" вообще вводные в не вводные превращает. Но это очень сложно и надо обсуждать с учёными. (Кстати, хороший пример для общего "но". "Это" у меня не общее. Такое бывает крайне редко, Розенталю не попадалось.)

Comment: Сколько мыслей, и все без доказательств (ссылок нет),  Так чо ловлю вас за руку на субъективности мнений, помните?  Розенталя вспомнили? Недавно опять по нему  неуважительно прохаживались, а вы рядом стояли и головой кивали, принципиальный вы наш.

Comment: С "но" просто интонация, вторая часть не следствие, как у Розенталя, а тоже к "но" относится. А второе вряд ли вы поймёте. "Действительно" может выражать согласие и быть независимым: *Действительно. Тебе же можно.* (Вводное слово не может быть одним в предложении.) Так вот "же" этому способствует, оно обрывает примыкание. Но это для учёных, не для вас.

Comment: Еще одно правило про вводные слова придумали? Помедленней, пожалуйста, я не упеваю записывать. И если это не для меня, то  зачем вы мне это говорите, идите к ученым. Там вас оценят и медаль дадут.

Comment: Но там реально есть за что! А в других случаях его защищал. Просто чтобы рассказать то, что обнаружил. А к чему такое правило? На пунктуацию не влияет, вводное оно или нет.

Comment: Ну, все, дальше неинтересно.  Пока, до новых встреч.

Comment: Можно чуть-чуть попробовать. *Действительно, нужно учитывать все эти особенности при анализе. Действительно, нужно же учитывать все эти особенности при анализе.* В первом случае оно примыкает (нет чёткого ударения), а во втором случае "действительно" произносится отдельно из-за "же" (нужно чёткое ударение и пауза), а "же" делает фразу новой и независимой. Надеюсь, что хоть чуть-чуть что-то увидите. Ну хотя бы разницу...

Comment: Действительно, проще уж дать один ответ самому, чем написывать простыни в попытках переубеждать кого-то.

Comment: @user190920 Хотелось переубедить. 10 раз прошёл бы мимо этого вопроса, если бы кто-то не назвал вводным.

Comment: Нашёл очень хороший пример с вводным "точно" (вы же любите примеры): «Гроза, — подумал я: и точно, была гроза.» Тургенев. Здесь нет реакции, нет вспоминания, нет самостоятельности, поэтому вводное. А в исходном примере не так.

Comment: А вот это должно разрешить дискуссию: 2. **Частица**. То же, что «будто бы, как будто». Не требует постановки знаков препинания. *Ты точно расстроен чем-то?* Н. Помяловский, Очерки бурсы.
То же, что «да, так, верно». **Употребляется в качестве ответной реплики. Выделяется знаками препинания или оформляется как отдельное предложение-реплика.**
*«Русский поэт, слово из трех букв, последняя Т». – «Фет». – «Точно!»* https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/702/точно

Comment: Дискуссия закончится, если вы дадите краткий и убедительный ответ, желательно со ссылками. Иначе (если я буду вам отвечать) ее отправят в чат или просто удалят. И все ваши мысли пропадут даром :))

Comment: Эта ссылка даёт ответ и без меня. Ничего, отвечайте. Второй раз в чат оно вряд ли уйдёт.

Comment: Спасибо, не буду, просто надоело говорить на одну и ту же тему.

Comment: По ссылке сказано Грамотой (это их словарь), что в ответной реплике частица. Что ещё требуется доказывать?

Comment: Ну не доказывайте, если всё уже доказали.

Comment: Ну тут же только ссылкам верят, с логикой не дружат и т.п. Вот ссылка...

Comment: Хорошо хотя бы то, что вы дружите. Вот дали бы ответ, тогда все бы это увидели. А так сложно добраться до вашей логики. Лучше отвлекитесь и найдите ошибку  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/473737/Какие-способы-цитирования-используются-в-предложениях-их-названия-отличия-меж

Answer (score 0):

Сразу отвечу на вопрос - это точно не вводное. А далее следует рассуждения.

Все наречные вводные в начале предложения можно считать невводными.
Слово `точно` как правило вводное по справочнику Фрамполь. `И точно, места удивительные (И.Бунин).`

Например, возьмем очевидно вводное:
`Действительно, это так!`. Перепишем иначе: `Действительно! Это так!` Ну и теперь просто слепим сложное предложение из двух простых, очевидно без всяких вводных: `Действительно, это так!`. Таким образом всегда, когда срабатывает такой трюк, мы вправе считать как угодно. Но **действительно** можно воткнуть и в середину предложения и тут уж как не крути придется признать, что это вводное. И чтобы не делать разных вариантов взависимости от порядка слов, просто признали **действительно** везде вводным.

Проверим теперь исходное предложение по критерию вводности:

```
`И точно, места удивительные (И.Бунин). `
`А точно, тебе же можно `

`Места, и точно, удивительные (И.Бунин). ` // Ок
`Тебе же, а точно, можно ` // Фейл
```

Видим, что критерий не удовлетворяется, значит слово не вводное.
И это будет работать с абсолютно любым вводным словом - оно перестает быть вводным в связке с союзом а!

```
Тебе же, а очевидно, можно // Фейл 
Тебе же, а действительно, можно // Фейл
```

Comment: К сожалению, некоторые вводные умеют примыкать к союзу "а", например: *значит, следовательно, вообще*. Думал про этот аргумент изначально, но он не канает. Но похоже, что "а" реально превращает "действительно" в не вводное (судя по интонационному примыканию). А вот "точно" с "а", наоборот, больше примыкает к фразе. Может, вы уже видели, по этой ссылке сказано, что в ответной реплике частица: https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/702/точно А в примере Бунина нет ответной.

Comment: Я вот все еще думаю насчет союза, все таки здесь Аааа долгое и имеет совсем другой смысл нежели обычный союз а. Так что здесь статус А под вопросом. Или вы можете предложить какие-то аргументы сближающие союз а в середине предложения и длинное Ааа вначале предложения?

Comment: Вообще - как правило не вводное. См справочник: "Вообще о писательской работе существует много предвзятых мнений и предрассудков ". Значит и следовательно можно трактовать как невводные и придать им особый статус. Что касается примыкания к А наречных вводных, то в чем то вы правы, хотя их всегда можно трактовать как сложные предложения: А ведь действительно, он ушел. итд

Comment: Два варианта, если долгое, то междометие, а не союз. "Вообще" обособляется, когда после "а". По факту это вводные в качестве союзов. Хотели "значит" отделять с одной стороны, как союз, но не прижилось (убрали это правило). "Точно", в отличие от "действительно", самостоятельно звучит (в таких случаях). Но тут "же" мешает считать их вводными. Пытался как-то в комментариях передать. Происходит нечто подобное: *Точно, что тебе можно. Точно, что тебе же можно* (не работает). И они там отдельно, к фразе не примыкают.