# Какие способы цитирования используются в предложениях (их названия, отличия меж собой...)?

Tags: грамматика, косвенная

> 1. Оценивая заслугу адмирала, императрица Екатерина II отмечала в
>    письме к нему, что «должна этою победой вашим великим дарованиям,
>    вашей твёрдости, вашей непоколебимой решимости к славе Российской
>    империи». Грамматическая ошибка есть (по составителю задания).
> 2. Как отметил в своём судовом журнале один из капитанов XVIII века,
>    «корабль был атакован морскими прожорами (то есть акулами), от которых
>    едва отделались, обороняясь всем своим оружием». Грамматической ошибки нет (по составителю задания).

По сути, оба предложения - сложные: 1. [Предложение + Придаточное косвенное]; 2. [Придаточное + Предложение косвенное]. Но в чем, собственно, различия между ними? По составителю задания, первое пр содержит придаточное косвенной речи, где смешана прямая речь и косвенная речь ("должна",я). Однако таким образом можно и рассуждать о втором предложении, разве нет? ("отделались, своим", мы)

Comment: Во втором случае я бы, если честно, расставил знаки препинания как при прямой речи.

Comment: Может быть, в первом?

Comment: Но по правилам ведь разрешается цитирование косвенной речи с помощью союза "что" и последующих кавычек (цитата может начинаться с многоточия, а может и не начинаться).

Comment: Притяжательные местоимения проверьте, там ошибка.

Comment: вашим - нему?  ...

Comment: Надо писать "его твердости", а тогда это уже не будет цитатой. Значит, нужна прямая речь.

Comment: тогда это уже будет ошибка в цитате (так как будет "Я должна этою победой его великим...", что целостно является верным не будет). Ведь, по сути, слова из цитаты были бы адресованы кому-то третьему, а не второму лицу

Comment: "Екатерина писала, что она должна его великим дарованиям...". Это правильный пересказ текста с помощью косвенной речи, но не цитирование.

Comment: @Sharon Вы уже её нашли. Можно просто изменить местоимение и убрать кавычки.

Comment: Вопрос еще в том, как объяснить, что во втором предложении косвенная речь взята в кавычки

Comment: Косвенную речь что-то должно вводить. Обычно это "что". А оборот с "как" указывает, что информация будет перефразирована, а если она дословная, то в нём нет смысла и нужна прямая речь. Так что как-то не очень.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. В первом предложении для цитирования нужно использовать **прямую речь.** Использование **косвенной речи** невозможно, так как для ее правильного построения требуется согласование лица для местоимений:

*Оценивая заслугу адмирала, императрица Екатерина II отмечала в письме к нему: "Я должна этою победой вашим великим дарованиям, вашей твёрдости, вашей непоколебимой решимости к славе Российской империи".*

2. Во втором предложении оформление верное, там при цитировании используется **вводное предложение**. В этом  случае текст заключается в кавычки, а вводные слова указывают на источник цитаты, например: Как сказал Репин, «вдохновение – это награда за каторжный труд».

*Как отметил в своём судовом журнале один из капитанов XVIII века, «корабль был атакован морскими прожорами (то есть акулами), от которых едва отделались, обороняясь всем своим оружием»*.

**О вводных предложениях с союзом КАК**

1. Запятыми выделяются вводные предложения следующих типов:

(3) предложения, присоединяемые посредством **союзов или союзных слов**:  *Я, **как** несомненно можете по мне видеть, человек совсем незначительный (Леск.). **Как** выражаются моряки, ветер крепчал (Ч.).*  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=124#pp124

Comment: Оборот с "как" используется, когда что-то перефразируют. Он буквально означает, что будет изменение.

Comment: Он буквально подразумевает: *Скажу так, как кто-то сказал (сравнение), а не процитирую.*

Comment: *«Корабль был атакован морскими прожорами (то есть акулами), от которых едва отделались, обороняясь всем своим оружием», как отметил в своём судовом журнале один из капитанов XVIII века.* Если так, то вообще нелепо получается, прямо напрашиваются слова автора. А при исходном порядке тоже надо.

Comment: На грамоте.ру пишется следующее:
б) ставят точку, если цитата не является самостоятельным предложением, а выступает как часть придаточного (даже если перед закрывающими кавычками стоит многоточие, вопросительный или восклицательный знак):

Б. Л. Пастернак подчеркивал, что «самое ясное, запоминающееся и важное в искусстве есть его возникновенье...».

Comment: Но, по-моему, необязательно, что цитата будет состоять из только из придаточного предложения. Нужно как раз-таки найти это правило...

Comment: @oleedd  "Оборот с "как" используется, когда что-то перефразируют. Он буквально означает, что будет изменение". Откуда, почему? Продвинутый уровень?

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Автор говорит, как кто-то говорил, подобным образом, а не так же само, точь-в-точь.

Comment: @oleedd  Выдумки. Если автор пересказывает, то нет кавычек, если приводит точные слова – есть.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Не выдумки. В таких случаях всегда текст меняется, переделывается под ситуацию. Если приводит точные слова, то пусть использует прямую речь или связывает союзом, чтобы была реально косвенная. Иначе в "как" нет смысла.

Comment: Вводные слова могут указывать источник цитаты? Вроде бы был вопрос. Тогда признали, что это не норма.

Comment: Может, Nektoid задавал. Было при нём...

Comment: @oleedd Бездоказательно, неубедительно. Вам бы написать какую-нибудь книжку по всем накопленным вами материалам (без иронии).

Comment: @oleedd  Вы сегодня перетрудились, говорите то, что явно противоречит здравому смыслу и практике письма.  «Литература есть сознание народа, цвет и плод его духовной жизни», – говорил В.Г.Белинский.  Можно записать: Как сказал Белинский (по словам Белинсого), «литература есть сознание народа, цвет и плод его духовной жизни». Или нельзя? Это вам вопрос для размышления на завтра.

Comment: @Sharon Не желательно менять слова автора на вводное. Это уже обсуждалось. Но меня это как-то не очень волнует. Говорю, что при "как" текст подстраивается под ситуацию и говорится подобным образом (что подразумевает слово "как"), а не дословно.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Sharon уже сайт создала. И что, много можно на этом заработать? Пару копеек...

Comment: Кстати, без меня обсуждалось...

Comment: Ссылки на учебные материалы;   https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/313-osnovnyesposobycitirovaniya.html     https://infourok.ru/podgotovka-k-oge-sposobi-citirovaniya-1175844.html     https://mcoip.ru/blog/2022/12/27/sposoby-czitirovaniya/

Comment: Найдите в ПАС или у Розенталя. А по этим ссылкам в примере отсутствует тире перед "это", такой себе источник. Вводные используются, когда что-то перефразируется. "По словам" используется, когда информация основана на чьих-то словах, когда фраза соответствует чьим-то словам, а не представляет собой эти слова. Это если строго. Видимо, такую строгость соблюдать не хотят, как и тире перед "это".

Comment: Ну это не критично, просто придираюсь даже к мелочам. Чтобы грамотность была абсолютной...

Answer (score 2):

**Второй ответ (о комментариях)**

**1. В справочнике есть все разрешенные правила**

Если правила нет, то такое написание не разрешено?
Конкретного правила о цитировании У Розенталя действительно. Но справочник желательно рассматривать не как сборник правил, а как сборник **решенных типовых задач**. Эти решения соответствуют своду правил, принятых в 1956 году. Но нельзя решить абсолютно все задачи, а вот принцип их решения хорошо бы усвоить.

**2. Вспомним уроки математики в школе**

Сначала учитель объясняет решение **типовых** задач  по теме на конкретных примерах. Потом школьники решают практически такие же задачи, чтобы освоить их на практике. Затем даются **более сложные** задания,  над которыми приходится думать самому.

И вот контрольная работа, где даны варианты разной трудности. Обычно посредственные ученики решают первый тип задач, который можно списать по аналогии. Работа так себе, на троечку, но обижаться не приходится — уровень знаний определен объективно.

**3. В правописании как в математике**

И вот в правописании точно такая же ситуация. В правилах даны решения типовых задач **базового уровня.** А если уровень чуть выше и такого решения в правилах нет? Такие задачи и их нестандартные решения надо запретить?  Сказать так: «Нельзя!  Нужно ездить только по правилам»!

Но это **школьные** правила, невозможно требовать их абсолютного соблюдения  в литературе. Там нестандартных задач бывает достаточно.

**4. Цитаты как элементы предложения**

По Розенталю подлинные выражения (цитаты), вставленные в текст в качестве элементов предложения, выделяются кавычками, но двоеточие перед ними не ставится (см. примечание)  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=159#pp159

Вводные предложения с союзам КАК в справочнике рассматриваются в теме вводных слов, просто эти предложения надо применить при цитировании. И еще вот что интересно: **в самом задании** указано, что такое решение правильное. Так зачем же сомневаться?

**5. В грамматике не допускаются собственные решения**

*Союз КАК используется, если  текст меняется, переделывается под ситуацию. Если приводит точные слова, то пусть использует прямую речь или связывает союзом, чтобы была реально косвенная. Иначе в КАК  нет смысла.*

Но разве это правильно?  Союз КАК многозначный, он применяется во многих грамматических конструкциях. Уподобление — это не единственное его значение. В этой теме его можно применять в паре с ТАК ("он сказал так" или "как он сказал").

В грамматике все действительно строго, там **«своя» точка зрения** недопустима. Это динамичная и развивающаяся наука, но в ней работают настоящие специалисты. Решения долго обсуждаются, прежде чем будут включены в вузовские (не школьные!) программы. Поэтому «реформировать» грамматику по своему усмотрению **недопустимо**,  и на каждое утверждение из грамматики обязательно требуется **ссылка.**

А вот правописание — наука **прикладная,** там можно использовать общепринятую грамматику при решении различных задач.

**6. Практика письма**

В Нацкорпусе очень много примеров, причем разного вида. Вариант востребованный, и хотелось бы иметь хотя бы какие-то утвержденные правила по теме.

Как писал Андрей Платонов, «истинно буржуйская субстанция».

Как писал Ф. Бродель, «эта буржуазная жестокость безмерно усилится в конце ХVI в. и еще более в ХVII в.»

Как писал Пруст, «жизнь есть усилие во времени» ― и если усилия нет, то и ощущения жизни нет.

Как писал Зиновьев о своем питомце, «он прекрасно произнес стихи Жуковского к морю и заслужил громкие рукоплескания.

Как писал П. Я. Чаадаев, «… у всех народов есть период бурных волнений, страстного беспокойства…»

И, будто их усилиями, в природе потеплело. Зато, как писал Пушкин, «сделалась метель»

О союзе КАК можно прочитать материал в книге
[А. Ф. Прияткина. Русский язык.  Синтаксис осложненного предложения. 2016
§ 17 - 19](https://scicenter.online/sintaksis-uchebnik-scicenter/russkiy-yazyik-sintaksis-oslojnenno.html)

**Примечание.** Ответ можно обсуждать при желании, но я не буду принимать участие в дискуссии, всё уже сказала:))

Comment: Грамотность написанного, а не грамотность человека, перевернули с ног на голову. Вы притянули за уши пункт 6. Это не задача, которую нужно решить, это способ оформления, серьёзная вещь. В справочниках указаны нормальные способы оформления. Чего же там не указали способ, который эти методисты называют основным (**базовым**)?! А у Розенталя цитата в качестве члена предложения, а тут она всё предложение занимает. И у Розенталя не только базовое, он, как он говорил, старался делать акцент на трудные случаи. И вы говорите про точку зрения? Да у вас почти всегда точка зрения, а не объективность.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение. Не понравилась моя точка зрения? Вот и мне не  нравятся комментарии, то есть ваша точка зрения,  но у нас есть свобода выбора.  В задании указан верный вариант, но вы и его взялись оспаривать.  Для вас приводимые примеры неубедительны, а  у Розенталя НИЧЕГО не сказано о таком варианте. Вы же настаиваете на СВОЕМ решении, вопреки всем имеющимся материалам по этой теме.

Comment: Не сказано, потому что основным, как заявляется, он не является.

Comment: На Грамоте такого нет. Было бы, если это было бы абсолютно нормальным. Новаторство методистов...